# What is the raw value & scale value functionality of analog read() of ESP32 ? (Provided for UNO for reference)

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32

What is the difference between ESP32 Dev kit & Uno for **analogread() Function?**

As Uno -0 to 1023
As Esp 32 Dev Kit -0 to 4095

**So what will be the raw val & scale val ?**

**For UNO -**

```
int Rawval = analogRead(analogPin);
Serial.print("Rawvalue from Analog input =");
Serial.print(Rawval);
Scaleval = map(Rawval, 0, 675, 0, 20);
Serial.print(" Scaled Value =");
```

**What will be for ESP32 Dev Kit?**

**Ref UNO-**
// For 3V3 input to read 100%, 3V3 of 5V ref = (3.3 / 5) * 1023 = 675

/// === RELAY code ===

```
// raw value 675 correspond to 20%, so for 5% we will get 169
  if ( Rawval < 169) digitalWrite(RELAY_pin, HIGH);  
  else  digitalWrite(RELAY_pin, LOW);   
}
```

**What will be for ESP32 Dev Kit?**

Comment: Look in the help section under the question mark  in the editor about code quoting. I'd use the triple-backtick method for you, but you've got something weird around `For UNO -int Rawval` and I don't want to break things as much as fix them.

Comment: one is 10 bits of data and the other is 12 bits of data ... it appears that the question is not about `analogread()` at all, but about something else ... please update your question and ask about the real focus of your question

Comment: what is `raw val` and `scale val`?

Comment: QUESTION IS CLEAR?

Comment: no, it is not ... the code is also not formatted properly, so it is difficult to read ... please format the code ... as @timemage already said, put ``` on a separate line before the code and also after the code

Comment: Raw value is analogous sensor value..
Scale value is after mapping using the map function of raw value of the sensor.

Comment: I want exactly the same functionality at ESP32 dev kit as reference of UNO

Comment: When the read voltage is maximum that is 3.3V digital output is equal to 4095 for ESP32

Comment: Well then, go ahead. Use your transfer power to compare that with the 1023 maximum of the Uno. -- And, please, format your question.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Confusion! Here also, As you said that code for UNO was provided by someone expert.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How to map for ESP32 (As 4095 for 3.3v)? Enclosed Logic is for uno.                               
 ''' // For 3V3 input to read 100%, 3V3 of 5V ref = (3.3 / 5) * 1023 = 675
  Scaleval = map(Rawval, 0, 675, 0, 20); '''
''' // raw value 675 correspond to 20%, so for 5% we will get 169'''
Kindly modify this for ESP32 (4095)-- Enclosed Logic is for uno.
If you can enclose logic behind that will also fine for me based on calculations
Also for 0.1%